# How to avoid slashes to show up when browsing directory listings

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So far I have the following configuration in my .htaccess file:

```
IndexOptions HTMLTable
IndexOptions FoldersFirst
IndexOptions IgnoreCase
#IndexOptions SuppressRules
#IndexOptions SuppressDescription
IndexOptions SuppressLastModified
IndexOptions SuppressSize
IndexOptions SuppressColumnSorting
IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble
#IndexOptions ScanHTMLTitles
IndexOptions NameWidth=*
IndexOptions DescriptionWidth=*
HeaderName /header.htm
ReadmeName /footer.htm
IndexIgnore ..
IndexIgnore header.htm
IndexIgnore footer.htm
...
```

I need to add something to my .htaccess file so every trailing slash doesn't show up when listing the folders and subfolders in my page.

My page doesn't have an index.htm file and works simply displaying all the folders and directories, like this:

```
AB/
AC/
BA/
BR/
FL/
FO/
...
```

Inside AB/ you have many other folders:

```
aback/
abacus/
abaft/
abandon/
aberration/
abet/
...
```

Inside abacus/ you have many other folders too:

```
translation1/
translation2/
translation3/
...
```

I'd like the slashes not to show up when browsing the directory listings. I've been searching the web for two days but I haven't found an answer, or perhaps I have but don't know how to use it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try [this website](https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/). It has lots of examples about styling your .htacces directory views.

Answer (score 0):

By default, mod-dir adds a trailing slash  to existing directories if they accessed without it. To disable the directory slash ,you can use the following line in your htaccess :

```
DirectorySlash off
```

This allows you to visit a directory without traling slash and tells **mod-dir** not to add a trailing slash  if an existent directory is requested.

To remove the trailing slash from uris, you can use this :

```
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The trailing slash keeps showing up in my directory listing and with the second option the server displays an error page.